# Plotly Sunburst OnClick Event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, plotly, sunburnt

I'm using sunburst from Plotly within React , My issue is on the event onClick , when this happens at the second level the chart restyled as default, exists any way when on Click method set as default false the restyle object?